# How to configure Spring's Rabbit Template to throw exception on timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've been looking on google for a bit by now and I can't find a solution to my problem.
The problem is the default behavior of RabbitTemplate's methods, namely `convertSendAndReceive()` and `convertSendAndReceiveAsType()`.

When you invoke these methods and they are not processed and replied to (default direct reply-to with `queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`) the RabbitTemplate simply returns `null` response instead of indicating that message was not replied to.
That is pretty important when you send almost empty body on queue and expect to receive like user's books or something similar, with `null` response you can't tell if user has no books or if message wasn't processed in time.

Example invocation

```
final List<String> messages = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("getMessagesQueue", 0, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
```

I found a workaround for this - using AsyncRabbitTemplate as it's RabbitConverterFuture throws exception on method .get(timeout), but that's not my go-to. I don't want to have to use AsyncRabbitTemplate just to get notified on unprocessed message.

Example

```
final AsyncRabbitTemplate.RabbitConverterFuture<List<String>> messages = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("getMessagesQueue", 0, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});

try {
    messages.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    // message not processed
}
```

***My problem is how to configure RabbitTemplate*** (configure template itself, not wrap template calls with aspects, decorator, proxy or similar) ***to actually throw some exception instead of returning null values.***

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such feature; feel free to open a new feature request on GitHub. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues